# What they really mean with "volume' in phase diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, definition, volume, phase-diagram

How can phase diagrams involve volume since it is extensive?  perhaps it is understood that we are talking about a specific volume? If the volume and pressure are known but I don't know how much substance is contained in that volume, how can I know the phase? A high pressure in a given volume can occur with a low density and a high temperature, or with a large density and a low temperature.  but they are conditions that tend to different phases... They aren't?

Comment: You are suppossed to know the amount of susbtance, then T is determined by the equation of state, so a point in the PV  diagram contains no ambiguous information about the state.

Comment: Thanks. But when they graph their PV diagrams they are implicitly assumed to be dealing with a given quantity of substance, for example one mole. If different amounts of substance were used, the diagrams would be different. They wouln't? This is an ambiguity that does not arise if two intensive quantities such as pressure and temperature (or density, or specific volume) are chosen. It's correct? @user178659

Comment: In other words, whenever I see a phase diagram that uses volume I have to assume that it refers to a mole of substance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can phase diagrams involve volume since it is extensive?  perhaps it is understood that we are talking about a specific volume?

Yes, the volume in a phase diagram is either the specific volume, m$^3$/kg, or molar volume, m$^3$/mol, both of which are intensive properties.

Dividing one extensive property by another extensive property gives an intensive value. For example, mass (extensive) divided by volume (extensive) gives density (intensive). Similarly, volume (extensive) divided by mass or moles, gives specific volume or molar volume (intensive).

> If the volume and pressure are known but I don't know how much
> substance is contained in that volume, how can I know the phase?

You have to know the total mass of the substance, as well as the fraction that is in the vapor or liquid phase, in order to determine the total amount that is in each phase.

For example if you are dealing with saturated steam (liquid water plus water vapor), all you know from the saturated water steam tables is the specific volume (m$^3$/kg) of the liquid phase and the specific volume of the vapor phase. But in order to get the volume of the liquid and vapor phase you need to know the fraction of the total mass that is in the liquid or vapor phase. For steam, the fraction that is in the vapor phase is called the "quality" $x$ of the steam. If you multiply that by the total mass you get the volume in the vapor phase. $1-x$ times the total mass then gives you the volume of the vapor phase.

> A high pressure in a given volume can occur with a low density and a
> high temperature, or with a large density and a low temperature.  but
> they are conditions that tend to different phases... They aren't

Not sure I follow you, but temperature and pressure are not independent variables in a two phase system, e.g., liquid water and water vapor. For example, at 1 atmosphere pressure the temperature of saturated steam is 100 C. Again, from the steam tables you can find the specific volume of the liquid and vapor phases, but in order to know what fraction of the total volume is liquid and what fraction is vapor, you need to know the quality of the steam, i.e., the fraction that is in the vapor phase.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course this helps thank you. It Is not true that dividing one extensive property by another extensive property gives an intensive value (think to volume divided by area) but this Is not the point here. I see that almost all the books in the graph write "volume" and not "specific volume", I find this *really* bad and I don't know how to interpret the graphs.

Comment: Are you sure they are using volume and not specific volume? Can you cite any references that I can take a look at? Re intensive v extensive properties,  all these sites make the same statement. https://www.thoughtco.com/intensive-vs-extensive-properties-604133  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties, https://psiberg.com/intensive-vs-extensive-properties/

Comment: I'm not sure about what they use. I'm sure about what they write. Examples of books specific about thermodynamics that write volume are Balmer or Fermi himself (section 15). I'm thinking if it Is a problem of bad notation and they should write specific volume.

Comment: Anyway I have done an example (taken from a quora answer) of ratio between extensive that Is extensive. It Is 100% sure that the rule extensive/extensive=intensive is not general.

Comment: @Haumea The specific volume is normally indicated by a lower case $v$.  As far as dividing one extensive property by another, the selection needs to make sense.  E.g., it makes no sense to divide internal energy $U$ by enthalpy $H$, yet they are both extensive properties.  Similarly, it makes no sense dividing the volume of a sphere by its surface area, which equals equals $1/r$  Typically, the denominator is mass, giving specific volume $v$, specific internal energy $u$, specific enthalpy $h$, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Phase diagrams were developed to monitor the operation of engines. The volume of a cylinder as well as the travel of the piston inside the cylinder can be measured.

Assuming air is not forced into the intake, then it is going to fill up the volume of the cylinder at ambient pressure and temperature. So V, P, and T are known for the initial quantity of gas. During combustion a PV indicator (see Watt's invention of the pressure volume indicator) shows the relationship between volume and pressure in the cylinder. I'm not sure if Watt was able to measure cylinder temperature.